# MapStruct : mapping multiple source fields to one target field

Tags: mapstruct

Consider the following POJOs:

```java
public class PersonVo {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

private class PersonEntity {
    private String fullName;
}
```

Using MapStruct, I want create mapper that `PersonVo` to `PersonEntity`.
I need mapping multiple source fields `firstName`, `lastName` to one target filed `fullName`.

Here is pseudo code what I want to.

[Want Solution A]

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullName", source = {"firstName", "lastName"}, qualifiedByName="toFullName")
    PersonEntity toEntity(PersonVo person);

    @Named("toFullName")
    default String translateToFullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return firstName + lastName;
    }
}
```

[Want Solution B]

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullName", source = PersonVo.class, qualifiedByName="toFullName")
    PersonEntity toEntity(PersonVo person);

    @Named("toFullName")
    default String translateToFullName(PersonVo pserson) {
        return pserson.getFirstName() + pserson.getLastName();
    }
}
```

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is my answer.

```java
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "fullName", source = ".", qualifiedByName="toFullName")
    PersonEntity toEntity(PersonVo person);

    @Named("toFullName")
    String translateToFullName(PersonVo pserson) {
        return pserson.getFirstName() + pserson.getLastName();
    }
}
```

Main point is that

> @Mapping(target = "fullName", ***source = "."***, qualifiedByName="toFullName")

It can make use source object by parameter.

Comment: One addition: you don't actually need the `qualifiedByName` unless you have  another method with the same signature: `String translateToFullName(PersonVo pserson)`.. e.g.: `String translateToFullNameAndAddress(PersonVo pserson)`. Qualifiers are meant to resolve conflicts.

Comment: You can also see a more complex example of merging multiple sources and additional data into the target mapping here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171232/cannot-make-work-mapping-method-selection-based-on-qualifiers/74172490#74172490

Comment: And @Sjaak is totally correct: qualification is ONLY needed when MapStruct is not able to disambiguate between mapping methods with the same signature and return value.

Answer (score 0):

First I would go with public abstract class for Mappers. Makes it easier to extend them and create inheritance between the generated code and the abstract class. But here is your solution:
You can achieve this by creating a @AfterMapping annotated method. So something like

```
@AfterMapping
default void concat(@MappingTarget PersonEntity person, PersonVo person) {
  ... manipulate the target value
}
```

[MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i'd like to separate each filed parser for clear.