# Cannot make work mapping method selection based on qualifiers

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to have a target bean mapped from attributes coming from 2 source beans. This is something very common that MapStruct easily does by [Controlling nested mappings](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#controlling-nested-bean-mappings). My problem is that I need to "calculate/validate" a target attribute taking as input one of the attributes in a source bean.

I will explain with a few code snippets.

First, we have the beans, something like (simplified):

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Builder
public class TargetBean {
    private final List<String> targetListTransformed;
    private final List<String> targetListDirectMapping;
    private final List<String> targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod;
    private final String targetString;
    private final Integer targetInteger;
}
```

One of the source beans:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SourceBeanOne {
    private final List<String> sourceListToTransform;
    private final List<String> sourceListDirectMapping;
    private final String sourceString;
}
```

and the other source bean:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SourceBeanTwo {
    private final Integer sourceInteger;
}
```

Then the mapping attempt:

```
@Mapper(uses = SourceOneExtractor.class)
public abstract class TargetBeanMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "targetListTransformed", source = "source1")
    @Mapping(target = "targetListDirectMapping", source = "source1.sourceListDirectMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod", qualifiedByName = {"sourceOneTransformer", "transformerTwo"})
    @Mapping(target = "targetString", source = "source1.sourceString")
    @Mapping(target = "targetInteger", source = "source2.sourceInteger")
    abstract TargetBean map (SourceBeanOne source1, SourceBeanTwo source2);

    List<String> mapTargetList(SourceBeanOne source1) {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // simulate a transformation
        result.add("one");
        result.add("two");
        return result;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have tried [Invoking custom mapping method](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-custom-mapping-method), where you can see see a dummy implementation what I need to do: use one, or more, attributes in SourceBeanOne to produce the List to be mapped into TargetBean.targetListTransformed.

That perfectly works. My problem came when I realized that I needed to produce another List for another Target attribute, doing different things with other attributes in SourceBeanOne. Another custom mapping method is not possible because MapStruct cannot disambiguate. That's how I ended trying [5.9. Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers). And this is the resulting qualifier class based on @Named (to avoid generating a bunch of @Qualified annotations):

```
import org.mapstruct.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Named("sourceOneTransformer")
public class SourceOneExtractor {

    @Named("transformerOne")
    public List<String> getterMethodOne(SourceBeanOne s) {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // simulate a transformation
        result.add("one");
        result.add("two");
        return result;
    }

    @Named("transformerTwo")
    public List<String> getterMethodTwo(SourceBeanOne s) {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // simulate a transformation
        result.add("three");
        result.add("four");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I got this error:

> No property named "targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod" exists in source parameter(s). Please define the source explicitly.

At the beginning I had to deal with Lombok-Mapstruct issues reading some other posts in Stack Overflow and MapStruct documentation ([Can I use MapStruct together with Project Lombok?](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok)), but once solved, everything is working and Lombok annotations are correctly processed before MapStruct's. But, just in case, I also tried with hand-made code for constructors, target builder and getters with the same result, so Lombok is not causing this. I also made sure I am using the right @Name annotation ([Why does @Name not work?](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Why-does-Named-not-work)).

My real use case (code here is just a simplification for the sake of clarity) source does not have any attribute named "targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod".

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the error finally gave me the hint: " Please define the source explicitly."
Looking at Mapstruct source I saw that it was trying to find an attribute in SourceBeanOne named "targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod". As there was not one, mapping was not possible and it failed saying "[...] define the source explicitly".
Despite none of the examples in [5.9. Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) indicated the source bean by means of the source parameter, I tried it and now it works.

I leave here the final code of the mapper and a test, for reference. The code of the qualifier is the same as in the question above.

The mapper:

```
@Mapper(uses = SourceOneExtractor.class)
public interface TargetBeanMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "targetListTransformed", source= "source1", qualifiedByName = {"sourceOneTransformer", "transformerOne"})
    @Mapping(target = "targetListDirectMapping", source = "source1.sourceListDirectMapping")
    @Mapping(target = "targetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod", source= "source1", qualifiedByName = {"sourceOneTransformer", "transformerTwo"})
    @Mapping(target = "targetString", source = "source1.sourceString")
    @Mapping(target = "targetInteger", source = "source2.sourceInteger")
    TargetBean map (SourceBeanOne source1, SourceBeanTwo source2);
```

}

A sample test:

```
class TargetBeanMapperTest {

    private static TargetBeanMapper mapper;

    @BeforeAll
    static void instantiateMapper() {

        // instantiate mapper under test
        mapper = Mappers.getMapper(TargetBeanMapper.class);
    }

    @Test
    void map() {
        final SourceBeanOne s1 = new SourceBeanOne(List.of("this", "list", "will be transformed"),
                List.of("this", "list", "will be directly mapped"),
            "sourceOneString");
        final SourceBeanTwo s2 = new SourceBeanTwo(66);
        final TargetBean t = mapper.map(s1, s2);
        assertNotEquals(s1.getSourceListToTransform(), 
            t.getTargetListTransformed());  // check that source1 list has been transformed
        assertEquals(List.of("one", "two"), t.getTargetListTransformed());
        assertEquals(List.of("three", "four"), 
            t.getTargetListTransformedWithAnotherMethod());  // check that source1 list has been transformed
        assertEquals(s1.getSourceListDirectMapping(), 
            t.getTargetListDirectMapping());
        assertEquals(s1.getSourceString(), t.getTargetString());
        assertEquals(s2.getSourceInteger(), t.getTargetInteger());
    }
}
```